# Callback from Altbeacon when detection is starting or stopping

Tags: java, android, altbeacon

I'm currently developing a small app that detect beacons with the [Altbeacon library](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/). I'm trying that to show a toast when the Altbeacon start and stop detecting beacons. But I can't find in the documentation a callback or something equivalent.

I already found a way to show a toast when the detection start but I can't find a way to show it when it stops.

```
private boolean isStarted = false;

@Override
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> collectionParam, Region region) {
    if (!this.isStarted) {
        this.isStarted = true;
        // show toast
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use monitoring APIs and the `didExitRegion` callback.  See the main examples page under Monitoring Sample Code for details.  https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

Comment: *Called when no beacons in a Region are visible.* is not what is search. My toast need to be showed then the user disable the bluetooth or the localisation and Altbeacon stop detecing...

Comment: It will still work for that purpose.  It will get called whenever no beacons are detected for ~20 seconds, even if caused by Bluetooth or location being turned off.